# SQLite.swift and M1 chip and simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, apple-m1, sqlite.swift

I have a project where I use `SQLite.swift`. Recently I got a MacBook Pro with a `M1` chip. After that the project runs fine on a device but when I try to run on simulator I get this error message from Xcode:

`Could not find module 'SQLite' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios-simulator.`

I use cocoa pods for adding `SQLite.swift` to my project. I tried to move it to `SPM` but the error is still present.
After searching for this error I found a work around: Open Xcode with this option: `Open using Rosetta`, but this to me seems as a hack.

Can this be fixed somehow at the SQLite.swift level?

- `SQLite.swift` version 0.13.0
- `Xcode` 13.2.1

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is trying to build for x86_64 which will make it run under Rosetta translation. SQLite.swift is building correctly for arm64 and will run natively on the M1 in Simulator. Due to the mis-match the overall build is failing. You are absolutely correct that opening Xcode under Rosetta is a hack and you're paying a memory + performance penalty by doing that.

I recommend checking your ARCHS and EXCLUDED_ARCHS build settings, along with your other dependencies. If you have a binary dependency that hasn't updated to support Simulator arm64 that might be causing Cocoapods to force the architecture to x86_64. Alternately you may have set those build settings long ago and never realized it.

The correct way to set this up today is:

1. Never touch ARCHS or SUPPORTED_ARCHS
2. Unless you have a binary dependency that hasn't updated don't set EXCLUDED_ARCHS either

By default Xcode will build for Simulator using your Mac's native architecture. In Debug builds it only builds that one architecture, for Release it builds all supported architectures (which may vary depending on what your Run Destination is). In this respect simulators are not any different from device builds.

Comment: Thank. you for the response. I will try your recomendations next week.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it.

In your project, Build Settings, Architectures:
- Base SDK: IOS
- Build Active Architecture only:
- Debug: Yes
- Release: No
- Excluded Architectures: Empty
- Supported platforms: Any platform

Be sure the build settings of the target are the same.

Comment: Thanks, this was it (under target) for me! I think I excluded the arm64 simulator SDK on my old mac for some reason

Answer (score 0):

targets->build settings-> build active architecture only=No. It's work for me.